# How to use single quote in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqldatatypes, quote

I retrieve customer information by using

```
WHERE UPPER(CustomerName) LIKE UPPER('%ALAN%');
```

Now, I'd like to pass in a variable `@CustomerName` when I create a new stored procedure. So, I changed my query like this:

```
DECLARE @CustomerName Nvarchar(100);
SET @CustomerName = 'ALAN';

WHERE UPPER(CustomerName) LIKE UPPER(''%'' + @CustomerName + ''%'');
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the modulo operator.

I suspect that it is because of the single quote that I used wrongly. How can I update my query to get the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be just that below. You're concatenating string literals with a variable value, you don't need to do anything special.

```
DECLARE @CustomerName Nvarchar(100);
SET @CustomerName = 'ALAN';

WHERE UPPER(CustomerName) LIKE UPPER('%' + @CustomerName + '%');
```

Note, you didn't incluse `SELECT` part, so I didn't include it either.

Answer (score 1):

there are extra quote is in your query, remove it =)

```
DECLARE @CustomerName Nvarchar(100);
SET @CustomerName = 'ALAN';

WHERE UPPER(CustomerName) LIKE UPPER('%' + @CustomerName + '%');
```

SAMPLE : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c5424/5